# Reading a large .DAT File

Tags: c#

I am trying to read a huge .DAT file.I even have the csv of the .DAT file from which I wish to read specific columns eg column 1 and 2 and write the columns to a listbox. But while reading I was getting B�A.

UPDATE:

This is my c# code

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            string path = "";
            ofd.FileName = "";
            ofd.ShowDialog();
            path = ofd.FileName;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path));
            foreach (char ch in br.ReadChars(5000)) 
            richTextBox1.Text += ch;
            br.Dispose();
        }
```

Please let me know if I am making a mistake in the above code and help me to rectify it.

Comment: Don't use File.ReadAllLines to read a big file. Use a StreamReader as [mentioned here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I recommend using a proper CSV parser to read your file, it will be a lot faster as it won't be reading everything into memory or allocating strings using `Split`. In fact, never use `Split` when reading files.